# Android emulator on Windows Hypervisor Platform error on Hyper V enabled system

Tags: android-emulator, windows-10, hyper-v

When I started emulator on my WIN 10 PRO with

> Emulator -avd Android_Accelerated_X86_Oreo -partition-size 512 -feature WindowsHypervisorPlatform

i've got the error:

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is properly installed and usable.
>   @little-monkey

Unfortunately its no way to set it enabled becouse I dont have this option in menu like: [properly options in WIN 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq79U.png)

I'd tried scf and dims to resolve error in Windows Update packages but it was useless. Thank you for help in advance!!!!